# Set up an Android device to only access Google Docs

Tags: applications, security, settings, google-docs

I would like to create a dedicated word processing device that can only access Google Docs (and possibly Google Drive) and nothing more. The idea is to configure it to be completely free of any other distraction. Is it possible to set up an Android device this way?